Logging from existing CSV and script to CSV - PowerShell
I'm trying to build some logging with trackers for a process here. The logging will take data from an existing CSV, data from the script output, and compare them so that if there is a duplicate it will add to the tracker and if there is a unique output, it will add it to the new csv line.
$APIData = $APIData.LIST
$CSVHistory = @()
$file = $filepath
$CSVHistoryFromFile = Import-CSV -Path $file
$TrackingData = $CSVHistoryFromFile | ForEach-Object {     "$($_.City);$($_.State);$($_.TicketCount);$($_.Price)" } 
$ScriptData = $APIData | ForEach-Object { "$($_.City);$($_.State);$($_.TicketCount);$($_.Price)" } 

foreach ($object in $APIData) {
  $APITemp = "$($object.City);$($object.State);$($object.TicketCount);$($object.Price)"  
  if ($APITemp -notin $TrackingData) {
    $CSVHistory += [PSCustomObject]@{
      City          = $object.City
      State         = $object.State
      TicketCount   = $object.TicketCount
      Price         = $object.Price
      Total         = 1
      LogTime       = $currentDate
      LastDeleted   = $currentDate
    }
  }
  else {
    $RepeatData = $CSVHistoryFromFile | Where-Object {     "$($_.City);$($_.State);$($_.TicketCount);$($_.Price)" -eq $APITemp }
$total = [int]$RepeatData.Total
$CSVHistory += [PSCustomObject]@{
  City          = $RepeatData.City
  State         = $RepeatData.State
  TicketCount   = $RepeatData.TicketCount
  Price         = $RepeatData.Price
  Total         = $total++
  LogTime       = [datetime]$RepeatData.LogTime
  LastDeleted   = $currentDate
}
  }
}

    $CSVHistory += $CSVHistoryFromFile | Where-Object {     "$($_.City);$($_.State);$($_.TicketCount);$($_.Price)" -notin $ScriptData }

$CSVHistory | Export-CSV -Path $file -NoTypeInformation

This logs but does not properly append and track ($total++) data.

It looks like there can be multiple entries for $APITemp within $CSVHistoryFromFile, so you're likely getting an array of objects back for $RepeatData, which is messing up $total. Try sorting the data and only taking the entry with the highest Total for $RepeatData. Maybe something like: $RepeatData = $CSVHistoryFromFile | Where-Object {     "$($_.City);$($_.State);$($_.TicketCount);$($_.Price)" -eq $APITemp } | Sort Total | Select -Last 1

tldr: change $total++ to ++$total

$total++: assign the current value of $total, and then increment it
(in your case, the incremented value is not used)
$total = 0
1..3 | foreach {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Number = $_
        Total  = $total++     # 0, 1, 2...
    }
}
$total     # 3

++$total: increment the value of $total, and then assign it
$total = 0
1..3 | foreach {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Number = $_
        Total  = ++$total     # 1, 2, 3...
    }
}
$total     # 3


In both of the examples above, the value of $total is 3 at the end. But in the first we assign the value to Total before incrementing, and in the second we first increment and then assign to Total.
